# simple hibernate session management

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

i'm a bit new in the world of hibernate and i lack knowledge in certain domain when it comes to java.I know for a fact that a good piece of software that uses hibernate use a session manager that can provide different kind of session.i'll like to create for now a simple session manager on top of which i'll build gradually the other implementations.thanks for reading

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Can you be more explicit?

Comment: Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement ;)

Comment: Ok i want "something" to manage the session in my application.so i'm tempted to pass a sessionfactory object and return a session using singleton pattern so i'm not sure about how to go about that implementation.how to implement a simple session manager that return a session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Spring session management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html), don't build this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [extended ThreadLocal pattern](https://www.hibernate.org/207.html).